# Как понять матрицу вращения?

Tags: javascript, css, математика, матрицы

В спецификации `css` есть вот такой [пример вращения матрицы](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#Rotate3dDefined), помогите его понять.

> A 3D rotation with the vector `[x,y,z]` and the parameter `alpha` is equivalent to the matrix:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> where:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно я не понимаю что подразумевается под `vector[x, y, z]`. Я бы мог представить что это вектор вокруг которого будет задана трансформация, но в `css` же нет такого.. Или же есть? И что там под альфой обозначено, угол?

Comment: это вектор по которому будет построена матрица поворота

Comment: @Grundy, можете более подробно, а то я не понимаю :) Объясните вот на каком примере. Есть квадрат 100х100 и координатами (0, 0, 0), который мне нужно повернуть на 90 градусов вокруг точки (50, 50, -50). Вот где тут тот самый вектор?

Comment: оооох :-) если не опередят вечером попробую с примерами все написать. Вам именно 3d поворот интересен?

Comment: @Grundy, мне нужно 3D поворот вокруг заданной точки на заданный градус. И ещё можно добавить чтобы поворот был полноценным, чтобы при повороте на 180 градусов была задняя часть, ну и естественно перспектива чтобы тоже присутствовала. Вобщем нужен полноценный поворот :) Это так сложно? Я жду пример, но был бы рад если бы подкинули статью на русском что именно я должен понять и желательно на js. А ещё нужно понимать что матрица в js экспонентная.

Comment: собственно все на самом деле просто, и достаточно посмотреть статьи по теме аффинные преобразования. В ссылке в вопросе дана матрица на которую умножаются координаты. Объяснения какое значение на что влияет(поворот, сдвиг, наклон и т.д.) можно так же найти в информации по аффинным преобразованием. Не совсем понятно что за _задняя_ часть в контексте html элементов к которым применяется поворот, и чем она должна отличаться от передней

Comment: @Grundy, если кот смотрит мне в глаза, а его хвост привязан веревкой к колу вбитому в землю, который олицетворяет точку вокруг которой происходят трансформации, то повернув его на 180 градусов, он будет ко мне уже не лицом.
И про искажение, скейл и прочее я понимаю в терминах матрицы 3х3, но не могу понять что такое "вектор по которому будет построена матрица".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39278/discussion-between-grundy-and-vas).

Comment: @Grundy, обсуждать нечего. Вы либо скажите как найти этот самый вектор, либо спасибо что попытались помочь. А просьба помочь его найти связана с тем, что Вы не можете объяснить что это за вектор.

Comment: @vas нельзя повернуть квадрат в пространстве вокруг точки. Точнее, повернуть-то можно - но это семейство преобразований, а не одно. Поворот в пространстве делается только вокруг **оси**.